# create document element from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use [Mozilla Readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability) stand-alone library for a personal project I am currently developing. The idea is to pass Mozilla Readability a document element and that after some parsing magic it returns the document's title, author, text, etc.

So, the first thing is dealing with how to get the HTML source of an external URL. I have dealt with that using an internal PHP file, which retrieves this external URL's source code.

After that, I call an AJAX GET to process the data returned by my PHP file. However, I am having lots of problems to convert this HTML source into an actual Javascript document element to pass to Mozilla Readability.

This is the code that I am currently using:

```
$('#btn_fetch').on('click', function() {
var url = 'https://www.rtl.be/info/monde/france/pierre-bellemare-s-est-eteint-a-88-ans-1025563.aspx';
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'fetchurl.php',
        data: {
            url: url
        },
        dataType: "html"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");
        // i don't know how to add "data" into "doc" element !
        var article = new Readability(doc).parse();
        alert(article.title);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Error:' . thrownError);
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what value exactly does the data returns in the callback but if it is a string value of the html source you can use jquery.parseHTML(https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) function to convert your valid html string into set of DOM nodes, by the way in your code you are not using the data anywhere in the callback.

Comment: Might not even need that library if all you want is title and author. Can do that with jQuery itself by wrapping response in `$()` and using jQuery methods on that object....the same as if the elements were in page Can also do a lot of this server side using dom parser and just send json response with data you need. If you elaborate on use case more it might  help

Comment: @charlietfl: It's not only author & title that I want to retrieve. I am also looking to retrieve the full content of webpages, but only the text not the full html. To give you an idea, Mozilla Readability is what Firefox uses behind the scenes when you click the "Toggle reader view" button. This way text is much easier to read and I want to take advantage of this technology.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered it was actually very easy. The line I was missing was...

```
 doc.body.parentElement.innerHTML = data;
```

it should be added here in the `.done` function

```
.done(function(data) {
    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");

    // you need to add it here
    doc.body.parentElement.innerHTML = data;

    var article = new Readability(doc).parse();
    alert(article.title);
})
```

Comment: you might add a bit more detail for your answer as in where exactly you had t oadd this line , that might help others in future who come in looking for the same issue

Comment: It goes right where the comment "i don't know how to add "data" into "doc" element !" was placed. Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam!